# What is the scriptural source of Yugala Maha Mantra used by Nimbarka Vaishnava?

Tags: vaishnavism, nimbarkacharya

Yugala Maha Mantra is a mantra used by Nimbarka Vaishnava. The mantra is as follows.

> Radhe Krishna Radhe Krishna Krishna Krishna Radhe Radhe Radhe Shyama
> Radhe Shyama Shyama Shyam Radhe Radhe

It is similar to Maha Mantra used by Gaudiya/Chaitanya Vaishnavas. Just replacing 'Radhe' with 'Hare' and 'Shyama' with 'Rama'. Gaudiya claim this mantra to be from Kali Santana Upanishad though with a different order.

So my question is what is the source of Yugala mantra?